# Adding elements to a diagram in UML Designer for Eclipse throws error

Tags: eclipse, uml-designer

I use UML Designer for Eclipse 4.7.0 and got the following error while trying to add a new element to a diagram:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details. loader
>   constraint violation: when resolving field "IS_DETACHMENT" the class
>   loader (instance of
>   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the referring
>   class,
>   org/eclipse/sirius/business/internal/session/danalysis/DanglingRefRemovalTrigger,
>   and the class loader (instance of
>   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for the field's
>   resolved type, com/google/common/base/Predicate, have different Class
>   objects for that type

Do I have to change some settings?

Answer (score 0):

UML Designer 8.0.0 compatible with Eclipse 0xygen 4.7.0 is not yet released, the current version is an alpha version. According to your error, it seems that there is an imcompatibility between the version of Guava needed by UML designer and the one you have installed.
Which version of guava is installed in your Eclipse?

Comment: I have installed Guava 1.4.0